# Why is intrinsic carrier density only equal to hole - or electron concentration?

Tags: analog, semiconductors

If carriers can be holes or free electrons, why isn´t the intrinsic carrier concentration equal to the sum of the free electron concentration and the hole concentration in the semiconductor?

Comment: Something to think about: What happens if you have holes (un-filled electron states) and free electrons in the same area of a semiconductor?

Comment: Aren´t holes and electrons in diffrent bands?

Comment: "Bands" - yes. But these are not kind of separate. Bands are just different energy levels. And nothing prevents an electron from radiating some of its energy and dropping into a hole.

Answer (score -1):

I dont get what you mean .In semiconductors the conductivity of the semiconductor $$\sigma$$ is equal to:

$$\sigma  = en_{e}\mu _{De}+en_{h}\mu _{Dh}$$

we take into account both the drift of electrons and holes